# Pass rest of arguments in a given callback function in TypeScript in strict mode

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function `A` that takes another function as an argument. Inside function `A` I want to execute given function with one explicit parameter and rest with given parameter of a function. Like this.

```
function t(g: number, p: any, b: any): void {
    console.log(g)
    console.log(p)
    console.log(b)
}

function execute(fn: (t: number, ...args: any[]) => void) {

    // But this is not working...getting this error --- 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them 
    const ar = fn.arguments.slice(1)
    fn(3, ...ar)
}

execute(t)
```

How can I capture `args` execute with `fn` in strict mode?

Comment: This is because you are using strict mode

Comment: Yes you are right can this be done in strict mode.

Comment: I don't think so this could be done in strict mode as per MDN Docs. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/arguments#:~:text=For%20strict%2C%20async%20function%2C%20and%20generator%20function%20callers%2C%20accessing%20the%20arguments%20property%20throws%20an%20exception.

Comment: Do not use `fn.arguments`, which is deprecated. You either want `args`, or plain `arguments` when using a non-arrow `function` - inside the definition of the `fn` that you're passing.

Comment: "*I want to execute given function with one explicit parameter and rest with given parameter of a function*" - that doesn't make sense. There are no "given parameter" values anywhere in your code. Did you mean `execute(t, 4, 5)` or `execute(g => t(g, 4, 5))`?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the fact that you're using strict mode, it doesn't make sense to use `fn.arguments` here since `fn` isn't being passed any arguments. Instead you can add an `args` parameter to `execute` and pass them to `fn`.

```
function t(g: number, p: any, b: any): void {
    console.log(g);
    console.log(p);
    console.log(b);
}

function execute<TRestArgs extends any[]>(fn: (g: number, ...args: TRestArgs) => void, ...args: TRestArgs) {
    fn(3, ...args);
}

execute(t, "p", "b");
```

I've added the `TRestArgs` type parameter to provide type safety. Now `execute(t, "p", "b", "x")` will raise an error because `t` only has three parameters.

Comment: Can it be done without changing `execute` function signature. My example was simplified in reality execute receives several functions as a parameter where each have arbitrary number of parameters.

Comment: I don't think so, at least not based on the code you've provided in your question. You have to get the parameters to the functions you want to call and you can't do that without passing them to `execute`.

Comment: @nicholasnet Please provide a real example then. Where do those parameters come from?